# Any limitation on using Unique column as partition key in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1

I have a scenario where i have only sequence number column that i can use in partition key,rest of the columns will create big partition on a node.

So my question is, is there any drawback of using sequence no in partition key?

As by doing this my select query  will scan whole table rather than going to specific partition.

Note :i have dynamic select statements.

Thanks

Comment: Or i  use timeuuid as partition key?

Comment: timeuuid or random uuid are good choices

Comment: Will it create any performance issue when i have millions of records and spread all over the cluster?And also is there any limitation/drawback on n number of partitions in a table.As each timeuuid value will be considered as a separate partition.